# Using 2 doctypes in a website

Tags: javascript, html

The code in my website has 2 doctypes.  Can some one tell me why.  I cannot post the code here because it is two long.  if you go to this link  http://725814.ignitewb.com/ and view page source you will see it.  I bought this website but I want to fix some of the things design wise and don't wont to break anything going on in the back end.  I was thinking that there were 2 doctypes that would render 1 if the page was displayed in internet explorer.  Is that correct?

Comment: I don't see any doctype when I view the source of that page.

Comment: All I see is a tiny Javascript.

Comment: The javascript performs a redirect. I went to that link http://725814.ignitewb.com/?bnc=1 and I only see 1 doctype.

Comment: You guys are correct.  I am sorry for wasting your time.  I must of pasted the code into my text editor 2 times.  Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, no, that is not 'correct', either in the literal sense or a validation sense. The page in question only has one DOCTYPE, and for what it's worth, all pages can only have on DOCTYPE. Declaring a secondary DOCTYPE in the HTML will cause the *first* DOCTYPE to be utilised, as the DOM is read top-to-bottom, and after having found a valid doctype, it ceases to look for any further DOCTYPES.

This can be seen by using a DOCTYPE for HTML 3.2:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<script>
document.write(document.compatMode); // CSS1Compat
</script>
</html>
```

HTML 3.2 triggers Quirks Mode, and would output "BackCompat" rather than the default Standards Mode, which outputs CSS1Compat.